# python django urllib2.request , post request, my code not working . data i am sending is not being detected

Tags: python, django, urllib2

this is the requirement :

All write APIs expect JSON-encoded content. Many also accept file uploads. Because of this, we expect API requests to have the content type multipart/form-data, and JSON bodies of requests are expected to have the name **data**.

```
$ curl -F file=@/Users/alunny/index.html -u username@gmail.com -F 'data={"title":"API V1 App","package":"com.alunny.apiv1","version":"0.1.0","create_method":"file"}' https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/apps
```

**From the above url, leave that email as i already have the auth token which i can use **

This is my code :

```
url='url?auth_token='+token  //i have token , so no probs

da = {"create_method" : "file","title":"s9fsdf"}
da = {"data" : da}
da = urllib.urlencode(da)
req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_data(json.dumps(da))
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data')
#req.add_header('Accept', 'application/json')  
result = ""

try:
    result = urllib2.urlopen(req)
except urllib2.URLError,e :
    print "Code : "+str(e.code)
    print e.read()
```

getting below error :

```
Code : 400
{"error":"no create_method specified: file, remote_repo, or hosted_repo"}
```

I think the way I am sending data is wrong, can anyone tell me the correct way . When we send data, it should have name "data" .

Comment: Along with changing the header to `multipart/form-data`, your request needs to have the promised structure.. Was the request successful after implementing @bruno's suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but it might work better urlencoding the json data than the other way round:

```
jsondata = {"create_method" : "file","title":"s9fsdf"}
data = {"data" : json.dumps(jsondata)}
data = urllib.urlencode(data)
req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_data(data)
```

Comment: Can u show me how to include file in python according to below curl url(below lines available at top part of question) : $ curl -F file=@/Users/alunny/index.html -u username@gmail.com -F 'data={"title":"API V1 App","package":"com.alunny.apiv1","version":"0.1.0","create_method":"file"}' https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/apps

Comment: @user1434480: please post another question for this since 1/ it's unrelated to your (now resolved) encoding problem and 2/ being a more general problem it might be of interest for someone else.